# How to set some user data when token generate using web api bearer token base authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

When token generate with flowing my own condition at that time I want to fetch    some data of login user.

I'm already done access token generate

Here is my Startup class:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var myProvider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider();
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = myProvider
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }


}
```

MyAuthorizationServerProvider class

```
public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly ReviewDbContext db;
    public MyAuthorizationServerProvider()
    {
        db = new ReviewDbContext();
    }
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var user = db.Reviewers.Where(x => x.Name == context.UserName && x.Password == context.Password).FirstOrDefault();
        var admin = db.Admins.Where(x => x.Name == context.UserName && x.Password == context.Password).FirstOrDefault();
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        if (admin != null && user == null)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserName", admin.Name));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Admin Ahasanul Banna"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else if (user != null)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserName", user.Name));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "User Ahasanul Banna"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("Invalid_grant", "Provided username & password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

AuthorizeAttribute class

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute :System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }
        else
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Postman[image]
My expected output like as: [image]
Where I set user data which I want with user generate token.
**How to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding claims to your token so in order to access them you need to decode the token. However, if you want your extra data to be outside the token (like the image you have painted), you can add them as different properties to the login response object:

```
                  var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {
                            "UserName", "AA"
                        },
                        {
                             "UserId" , "1"
                        }
                    });
                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
                    context.Validated(ticket);
```

Also, you need to add the following method to `MyAuthorizationServerProvider` :

```
 public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```